# Pass data from controller to controller withour parameter mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller and I want to send a data to another controllers method. But receiver controller's action method currently in use and I dont want to change its parameter 
Just simply want a value that I sent from other controller ? 
is it possible with ViewBag ? 
I just want something like

```
Controller1: {...  
ViewBag.Data = 10;   
...}
Controller2:{... 
if(ViewBag.Data !=null)
value = ViewBag.Data 
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass data from one controller to another and wish to discard the object once it reaches the other controller, you should use **TempData**.

Controller 1:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

TempData["data"] = 10; // somedata;

return RedirectToAction("/Controller2/Index");

}
```

Contoller 2:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  if(TempData["data"] != null)

  int i = (int)(TempData["data"]) // Perform unboxing
}
```